Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token Exchange Failing Occasionally with 'invalid_grant'
I'm implementing Google OAuth 2.0 for user login using Go (Gin framework). The flow is as follows:

User logs in through Google OAuth.
Google authentication server redirects to the callback URL with an authorization code.
In the callback API, I use the authorization code along with client_id, client_secret, etc., to request an access token.

Most of the time, the login works perfectly. However, sometimes, especially when a user logs in for the first time or after clearing cookies and cache, the login fails. The error message I receive is:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

The issue is that the login usually works well, and reproducing the problem is difficult. Even after clearing cookies and cache, the error doesn't always occur.
Here is how I have configured the OAuth2.0 endpoint in my Go (Gin) server:
var Endpoint = oauth2.Endpoint{
    AuthURL:   "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    TokenURL:  "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    AuthStyle: oauth2.AuthStyleInParams,
}

I'm using the "golang.org/x/oauth2" library and specifically the *oauth2.Config object to handle the OAuth flow. I use the Exchange method of *oauth2.Config to request the access token.
What could be causing this intermittent issue? Is there any known behavior where Google OAuth 2.0 imposes a timeout or rate limit for token exchange? Are there other configurations or best practices I should consider to address this problem?
If any additional information is needed or if there are questions, please feel free to ask. I'm happy to provide further details.
Here's the log information:
Failure case log
WRN body_size=35 client_id={IP} latency=10.003534611s method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=A4dHND7TQhIEVvvecZ1Atw%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none 
status_code=400

WRN body_size=35 client_id={} latency=10.003552757s method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=CwZlrQXiAaMaz3GoEuLQCw%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent
status_code=400

WRN body_size=35 client_id={} latency=10.00314175s method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=cAQCLBbXAda6pEaXrrhM6w%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&hd=mantech.co.kr&prompt=none
status_code=400

Success case log
INF body_size=59 client_id={IP} latency=8.590253031s method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=zaJN5jV3ABsQHaKtLs7Tzg%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none 
status_code=302

INF body_size=59 client_id={IP} latency=536.582051ms method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=yb3MO5sbA13FP0vzl7Cabw%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&hd=mantech.co.kr&prompt=none
status_code=302

INF body_size=59 client_id={IP} latency=6.561984536s method=GET path=/auth/google/callback?state=YAbHA_3BWLNAszUbd10MgJ%3D%3D&code={code}&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent 
status_code=302

